Flutterflow - trying to refresh (reload) the page after clicking an alert dialog leads to a grey screen in my smartphone
I am using the following code which I want when clicking the 'OK' button in the 'You have internet' alert dialog, to refresh (reload) the page (Scaffold).
    // Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/backend/schema/enums/enums.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'dart:io'; // Import Platform for checking the operating system
import 'package:internet_connection_checker_plus/internet_connection_checker_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; // Needed for closing the app
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';

class InternetConnectionMonitor {
  Timer? _timer;
  OverlayEntry? _noInternetOverlayEntry;
  OverlayEntry? _restoredInternetOverlayEntry;
  OverlayEntry? _modalBarrierEntry;
  bool _hasInternet = true;
  BuildContext? _originalContext;

  Future<void> startMonitoring(BuildContext context, String language) async {
    _originalContext = context;
    if (_timer == null) {
      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {
        await checkInternetStatus(context, language);
      });
      await checkInternetStatus(context, language); // Initial check
    }
  }

  void stopMonitoring() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer?.cancel();
      _timer = null;
    }
    removeNoInternetDialog();
    removeRestoredInternetDialog();
    removeModalBarrier();
  }

  Future<void> checkInternetStatus(BuildContext context, String language) async {
    final InternetConnection internetConnection = InternetConnection();
    final status = await internetConnection.hasInternetAccess;
    if (!status && _hasInternet) {
      _hasInternet = false;
      if (_noInternetOverlayEntry == null) {
        showNoInternetDialog(context, language);
      }
    } else if (status && !_hasInternet) {
      _hasInternet = true;
      removeNoInternetDialog();
      if (_restoredInternetOverlayEntry == null) {
        showRestoredInternetDialog(context, language);
      }
    }
  }

  void showNoInternetDialog(BuildContext context, String language) {
    String title = language == 'el' ? 'Χωρίς σύνδεση' : 'No Internet';
    String message = language == 'el'
        ? 'Δεν υπάρχει σύνδεση στο διαδίκτυο.'
        : 'You have no internet connection.';
    addModalBarrier(context);
    _noInternetOverlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.wifi_off, color: Colors.red),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text(title),
            ],
          ),
          content: Text(message),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                removeModalBarrier();
                if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
                  exit(0);
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    if (_noInternetOverlayEntry != null) {
      Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_noInternetOverlayEntry!);
    }
  }

  void removeNoInternetDialog() {
    if (_noInternetOverlayEntry != null) {
      _noInternetOverlayEntry!.remove();
      _noInternetOverlayEntry = null;
    }
  }

  void showRestoredInternetDialog(BuildContext context, String language) {
    String title = 'Connection Restored';
    String message = 'Your internet connection has been restored.';
    addModalBarrier(context);
    _restoredInternetOverlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.wifi, color: Colors.green),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text(title),
            ],
          ),
          content: Text(message),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_restoredInternetOverlayEntry != null) {
                  _restoredInternetOverlayEntry!.remove();
                  _restoredInternetOverlayEntry = null;
                }
                removeModalBarrier();
                // Trigger a rebuild of the current page
                if (_originalContext != null) {
                  (_originalContext as Element).reassemble();
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    if (_restoredInternetOverlayEntry != null) {
      Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_restoredInternetOverlayEntry!);
    }
  }

  void removeRestoredInternetDialog() {
    if (_restoredInternetOverlayEntry != null) {
      _restoredInternetOverlayEntry!.remove();
      _restoredInternetOverlayEntry = null;
    }
  }

  void addModalBarrier(BuildContext context) {
    if (_modalBarrierEntry == null) {
      _modalBarrierEntry = OverlayEntry(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
              ),
              ModalBarrier(
                dismissible: false,
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
      Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_modalBarrierEntry!);
    }
  }

  void removeModalBarrier() {
    if (_modalBarrierEntry != null) {
      _modalBarrierEntry!.remove();
      _modalBarrierEntry = null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> monitorInternetConnection(
      BuildContext context, String language) async {
    await startMonitoring(context, language);
  }
}

Future<void> monitorInternetConnection(
    BuildContext context, String language) async {
  InternetConnectionMonitor _monitor = InternetConnectionMonitor();
  await _monitor.startMonitoring(context, language);
}

The problem with this code is that when I click OK, the page becomes grey instead of refreshing (reloading). How can I achieve what I want to do? What do I need to change in my code?
